# Почему сумма unsigned char имеет тип int?

Tags: c++

В следующем примере:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
    unsigned char a, b, c;
    a = 100;
    b = 100;
    c = 100;

    int x = (a + b + c);

    std::cout << "typeid(a + b + c) = " << typeid(a + b + c).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "x                 = " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a + b + c         = " << a + b + c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

получаем вывод:

```
typeid(a + b + c) = i
x                 = 300
a + b + c         = 300
```

Как видим, сумма unsigned char'ов не переполнилась, а тип суммы оказывается int'ом. Это для меня странно, мне казалось, стандартом гарантировано переполнение беззнаковых типов с взятием остатка от деления на максимальное представимое число, то есть в примере выше x должен был бы оказаться равен 300 % 256 = 44 .

В чём моя ошибка? Желательно со ссылкой на стандарт или cppreference.

PS. Ссылка для экспериментов: http://cpp.sh/7t35b

Comment: Integer promotion

Comment: [Integral promotion](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom)

Comment: @AnT точно помнил что был дубликат с хорошим ответом, но найти не смог :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may be used:
>
> — An object or expression with an integer type (other than int or unsigned int) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of int and unsigned int.
>
> — A bit-field of type _Bool, int, signed int, or unsigned int.
>
> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions. 58) All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

Перевод:

> Cледующее может быть использовано в выражении везде, где может использоваться int или unsigned int:
>
> - Объект или выражение с целочисленным типом (кроме int или unsigned int), чей ранг целочисленного преобразования меньше или равен рангу int и unsigned int.
> - Битовое поле типа _Bool, int, sign int или unsigned int.
>
> Если int может представлять все значения исходного типа (как ограничено шириной для битового поля), значение преобразуется в int; в противном случае он конвертируется в беззнаковое целое. Они называются целочисленными продвижениями. 58)
> Все остальные типы не изменяются целочисленными продвижениями.

В вашем примере при запуске функции сложения, любой аргумент типа **char** автоматически преобразуется в **int**.

```
movb    $100, 13(%rsp)
movb    $100, 14(%rsp)
movb    $100, 15(%rsp)
movzbl  13(%rsp), %ebx
movzbl  14(%rsp), %edx
movzbl  15(%rsp), %eax
addl    %edx, %ebx
addl    %eax, %ebx
```

Компилятор хранит данные размером в один байт, а сложение выполняет как с целочисленными аргументами.